# Java 6 guava Predicate to Java 8 Predicate & Lambda

Tags: java, predicate

I have been developing in Java 6 and using guava predicates. But I want to switch to Java 8 and use java util predicates instead. I can simply convert the below method to use the predicate but is there a smart way to use Lambda expressions and reduce the number of lines of code ? Preferably remove the temp list I am creating ? I am googling for examples but all of them are very simple ones. Thanks for you help!

```
    private Predicate<Objt1> getLocalAttributesPredicate() {
    return new Predicate<Objt1>() {

        @Override
        public boolean apply(Objt1 input) {

            AttributeType attr = cache.get(input.getAttributeID());
            List<String> attrGroupids = Lists.newArrayList();
            for (AttributeGroupLinkType group : attr.getAttributeGroupLink()) {
                attrGroupids.add(group.getAttributeGroupID());
            }
            return attrGroupids.contains(localAttrGroupId) && !attrGroupids.contains(exclustionAttrGroupId);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
private Predicate<Objt1> getLocalAttributesPredicate() {
    return input -> cache.get(input.getAttributeID())
            .stream()
            .map(group -> group.getAttributeGroupID())
            .filter(id -> id.equals(localAttrGroupId))
            .filter(id -> !id.equals(exclustionAttrGroupId))
            .limit(1)
            .count() > 0;
}
```

So the predicate is returned as a lambda function, and it utilises the Stream API to traverse the list and convert its contents.

Edit: applied the optimisation suggested by @Aominè, thanks.

Comment: you can optimise this further with  `...limit(1).count() > 0;`

Comment: Very Elegant, Thanks.

Comment: The id in the filter is String, so I changed == to equals method.filter(id -> id.equals(localAttrGroupId)).filter(id -> !id.equals(exclustionAttrGroupId). But the second filter is not working, I am getting results from exclustion group. What I am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you using `!id.equals(exclustionAttrGroupId)`? I've updated my answer. I had to kind of guess the classes you're using, although the `==` vs `equals` was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you'd do it as of Java-8:

```
private Predicate<Objt1> getLocalAttributesPredicate() {
   return input ->  { 
         Set<String> accumulator = ...
         AttributeType attr = cache.get(input.getAttributeID());
         for(AttributeGroupLinkType group : attr.getAttributeGroupLink())
              accumulator.add(group.getAttributeGroupID());
         return accumulator.contains(localAttrGroupId) &&
                !accumulator.contains(exclustionAttrGroupId);
   };
}
```

Note, that I've also used a `Set` for the accumulator as the `Contains` method is much faster for a `Set` implementation than for a `List` implementation.